# Wordpress posts page content overlapped with sidebar

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm struggling to format my posts pages for my website. The content is overlapped with sidebar. I tried some css trick, but its not working. It will be a piece of cake for an css expert, kindly request you to spare few minutes and advise. Thanks in advance.

http://prfeed.in/2017/02/herman-miller-launches-new-aeron-chair.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might benefit from reading the guides on [ask], and how to write a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.entry table
{
width: 82% !important;
}
```

Add it into your style file.